# Can not get Data from API to ArrayList with Volley in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to show my data to RecyclerView but can not add item from API to ArrayList
Array is empty

This is my code:

```
ArrayList<SanPham> sanPhams;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sanPhams = new ArrayList<>();
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest =  new JsonArrayRequest(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.URL), new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        SanPham sanPham = new SanPham();

                        sanPham.setMaSanPham(jsonObject.getString("maSanPham"));
                        sanPham.setTenSanPham(jsonObject.getString("tenSanPham"));
                        sanPham.setHinhAnh(jsonObject.getString("hinhAnh"));
                        sanPham.setGiaBan(jsonObject.getInt("giaBan"));
                        sanPham.setThongSoKyThuat(jsonObject.getString("thongSoKyThuat"));
                        sanPham.setMoTa(jsonObject.getString("moTa"));
                        sanPhams.add(sanPham);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(sanPhams.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
            }
        });
        queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(sanPhams.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

When i toast size onResponse Array size is 4 (my data have 4 item) but Toast outside size is 0.
I'm tryed to fix it but array still empty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network response is a time dependent operation. When you call the toast from outside, it doesn't have any data till now. But inside on success method, it has the data. Because this method is called after receiving the data. If want to operate on the data after receiving from server, you can use an Java Interface.

In your case, something like:

```
public interface ResponseListener{
  void onResponseReceived(ArrayList<SanPham> sanPhams);
}
```

In your class:

```
ArrayList<SanPham> sanPhams;
ResponseListener listener;
```

then inside onResponse method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
    try {
       JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

       SanPham sanPham = new SanPham();

       sanPham.setMaSanPham(jsonObject.getString("maSanPham"));
       sanPham.setTenSanPham(jsonObject.getString("tenSanPham"));
       sanPham.setHinhAnh(jsonObject.getString("hinhAnh"));
       sanPham.setGiaBan(jsonObject.getInt("giaBan"));
       sanPham.setThongSoKyThuat(jsonObject.getString("thongSoKyThuat"));
       sanPham.setMoTa(jsonObject.getString("moTa"));
       sanPhams.add(sanPham);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(sanPhams.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
listener.onResponseReceived(sanPhams);
```

Comment: Thanks so much ^^ this helpful with me in my problem